# How to access a server side method from a dynamicaly generated html button by innerhtml of a div

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to access a c# method from a html button which is dynamicaly generated by innerhtml of a div.

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class demo2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private string dynamicTextBoxValue;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        TextPreview.InnerHtml ="<input type=\"submit\" name=\"btnSubmit\" id=\"btnSubmit\" value=\"Click Here\" runat=\"server\" onclick=\"Get_data\"/>";

    }

}

public void getdata()
{

    Response.Write("clicked.");
}
```

}

i want to access that getdata() method from that html button..help.plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not call a server side function directly from client (without registering it on server, refer @fubo answer below for this), if we can then this was a security threat. Anyone could call any function from browser by adding raw html to  a web page, like your case.

However we can do a postback and in page_load we can validate our input button to call the desired method.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                testdiv.InnerHtml = @"<input type=""button"" id=""btnSubmit"" value = ""Click Here"" runat = ""server"" onclick=""__doPostBack('btnSubmit','')""/> ";
            }
            else
            {
                var eventTarget = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString();
                if (eventTarget == "btnSubmit")
                {
                    getdata();
                }
            }
        }

        public string getdata() {
            Response.Write("clicked.");
        }
```

Comment: what is the error, are you using getdata name correctly?

Comment: error is, if i click that button..nothing happens..if i directly take a html button  and write there OnServerClick='getdata' it works..but if i generate a button through a divid.innerhtml..that time its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a Button this way

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnSubmit = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button();
btnSubmit.ID = "btnSubmit";
btnSubmit.Text = "Click Here";
btnSubmit.Click += getdata(); //wire up event

//assuming, TextPreview is a Panel or someting
TextPreview.Controls.Add(btnSubmit);
```

Method:

```
protected void getdata(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("clicked.");
}
```

Comment: no bro.my question was,i want to call a c# method from a html button which is generated dynamicaly.